# Docker: access to VPN domain from docker

Tags: docker, dns

There is some websource "http://vpnaccessible.com" where I need to download some RPM package via `wget`. And this web-source is accessible only from VPN. So I'm using Cisco AnyConnect VPN client to enter VPN, then I want to build image using Dockerfile where this `wget` command is listed.

The problem is: Docker can't access to that domain within container. So I tried to pass `dns` options in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, but not sure what DNS IP I should pass, because in my local there are default DNS `192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8`. I tried to pass in that array IP addresses of `docker0` interface, e.g. `172.17.0.1` -- didn't work.

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
   "insecure-registry": "http://my-insecure-registry.com",
   "dns": ["192.168.0.1", "172.17.0.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

I also tried to add this websource to `/etc/resolf.conf` but when I run docker to build image -- it's edited to the prev state (changes are not persisted there), and I guess, it's my Cisco VPN client behavior -- didn't work.

Also tried to add IP address of interface created by Cisco VPN client  to that `dns` -- didn't work

I also commented out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` -- didnt work

For sure, I'm restarting docker and NetworkManager services after these changes.

**Question**: Should I create some bridge between Docker container and my VPN? How to solve this issue?

Comment: were you able to solve your problem? I'm having the same issue here

Answer (score 3):

You can try using your host network instead of the default bridge one. Just add the following argument:

```
--network host
```

or

```
--net host
```

Depending of your docker version.

Comment: I was not able to access to domains behind the VPN from container using --net host